# Java App with Spring-MVC in Maven system that uses tomcat to listen on port 8080 executes HDFS API in local fs only

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, hdfs, java

I'm trying to implement a simple REST server using java/sprig-mvc/maven/tomcat that listens on port 8080 and executeed hadoop apis to do file operations on hdfs.
Eg:- Http req "http://localhost:8080/CounterWebApp/showhomedir" would trigger hdfs apis fs.getHomeDirectory() and fs.mkdirs() in the code below.

I added hdfs configurations to Configuration class using core-site.xml and verified it by printing the same in the code. Nevertheless, the file system accessed is only local and not hdfs.

I analyzed/explored many relevant docs and noticed that file system operations on hdfs can be done only using hadoop/yarn commands which means they are done in hadoop env.

Isn't there a way to access hdfs by running the application in java env itself??
Will adding any hadoop plugin in maven help?? Any appropriate suggestion would be invaluable to me!!

```
package com.mkyong.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
//Below packages for HTTPClient for webhdfs
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
//Hadoop package
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

@Controller
public class BaseController {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private static final String VIEW_INDEX = "index";
    private final static org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showhomedir", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
    try {
            //Trying hadoop api directly
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            System.out.println("configured filesystem = " + conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            System.out.println("Home folder - " +fs.getHomeDirectory());
            boolean success = fs.mkdirs(new Path("/user/edureka/testdirectory11"));
            System.out.println(success);
            //For JSP
            model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome");
            model.addAttribute("counter", ++counter);
            logger.debug("[welcome] counter : {}", counter);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return VIEW_INDEX;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a standalone program that connects to the HDFS and see that works and then you can replicate the same on web:

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 

FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://localhost:54310"), configuration);
FileStatus[] fileStatus = hdfs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/path"));

Path[] paths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(fileStatus);

for (Path path : paths) {
  System.out.println(path);
}
```

Many Java api's interacting with the HDFS system found [here](https://linuxjunkies.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/a-hdfsclient-for-hadoop-using-the-native-java-api-a-tutorial/).